# Filter bound data source

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

The CollectionViewSource

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <local:EDiscoveryCoreDataList x:Key="CoreDataList"/>
         <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsCoreData" Source="{StaticResource CoreDataList}" >
        </CollectionViewSource>
  </Window.Resources>
```

Now Bind this to DataGrid

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsCoreData}}"   SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="Data" Canvas.Top="29" Width="1063" Height="536" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

After binding the source now used multiple binding like below

```
<Run.Text>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PreSynonymConverter}" >
    <Binding ElementName="search" Path="Text"/>
    <Binding ElementName="synonyms" Path="IsChecked"/>
    <Binding Path=" List"/>
  </MultiBinding>
</Run.Text>
```

In this code List is a list of string which are filtered in the converter. In my project I have use this code 3 to 5 time. Now each time the converter filter the list and put the string into run. I want a resource that have multibinding like this and provide a resource and put the resource into the run tag.
Thanks. Hope you will understand my problem.

Comment: Do your filtering in code and expose the results as a property that you can data bind to.

Comment: You want the Run.Text statement as a resource?

Comment: No want such a resource which support multibinding and converter. Is it possible??